# Move folders from one dropbox to another

Tags: dropbox

I have 2 dropbox accounts namely A and B (both are free accounts)

I want to know, how do i completely move a folder from A to B free-ing up the correspondng size of that folder from A ?

I want to do this because the em-mail id linked with A is my majorly used one and most of my family and friends know that where-as the one i used for signing up for B is not. Hence I want to free-up stuff in account A so that people can still keep sharing stuff with me.

Comment: Assuming you had the desktop application, I don't see why you couldn't just **move** the folders from one user to another. But I can't be sure of this, since I never used the app.

Comment: Nope, I cant use the desktop app because, a afriend of mine just shared a 3gb folder with me ( he is a premium user) , and I have stopped syncing it with my desktop, so I just need to move atleast half of it to my other account so that this account i am using gets some free space

Comment: Then the other way I'm seeing is to do the following: 1) Download the folder (as a zip) from account A to your PC. 2)(Optional) Decompress the zip. 3) Upload the archive (with folders it's more complicated, but doable) from your PC to account B. 4) Delete folder in account A. Although it's what could be called as doing by hand.

Comment: Yes, I had this method in mind, but the problem is that I am living in a place with very slow internet speeds and the folder size is 3gba nd would take me forever to download

Comment: Well this can help. It's from the [Dropbox knowledgebase](https://www.dropbox.com/help/389/en). I'm sure you can adapt to your needs. Just **don't** share the folder you want to copy, by default Dropbox doesn't copy the folder. Make a **new** shared folder and move the folder you want to move to there.

Comment: Thanks Doktoro, I think I can make use of it. Just one question, Lets say i share a folder from A to B and go to B and accept it. Now I delete the folder in A, does it affect the shared folder in B in anyway?

Comment: According to the same post it shouldn't pose a threat, but, just in case, test it with say a text file.

Comment: I did it, I shared froom A to B, copied all into B, and deleted from A. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: @Greg if you figured out your solution, please post it below as a self-answer and mark it as accepted. That will indicate that the question has been solved, and help anybody else who happens upon it later.